# Horse racing game

Tags: arduino-uno

Basically i would like to create a horse racing game, (5 horses starting all to a point A and finishing in a random position to a point B).

I did an animated GIF for you to understand it more clearly :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOZvB.jpg

This exactly what i want to do, but in real.

I was thinking of using 5 motors (one for each horse) with a string they pull where the horse is attached on it (like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjuoCS9-pCY), and to create randomness at each race, do a random speed for each motors every 1 or two seconds and then stop when each horse hit the finishing line (by pushing a sensor ?). Finally when all horses hit the finishing line, the motors goes backward and get the horses back to the start line.

The horses will be tiny like 1 inch (2.5cm) and the distance from start to finish line will be like 20inch (50cm) and i need the race to last at least 5-10 sec so motors don't need to turn too fast.

I don't know if it is the best way or if it is even possible (and how ? with what components?)

I have been searching for solutions to my project but didn't found anything suitable yet so here i am..

Thank you a lot for you help

Comment: What is your question exactly? You want a solution to your project (would that be "assignment") - is that it?

Comment: I'd use some simple stepper motors for that. Using those, you will always know where all the horses are precisely, have precise control of speed, and negating the use of buttons at the finish.

Comment: Thanks @Gerben this is a start :) and yes nick i'm looking for help to know what component to use

Answer (score 1):

If it is going to be tiny, I would use continuous rotation servos and rubber belts. They are nice because you dont need motor drivers, unlike stepper motors. Also they consume a lot less power than stepper motors, so you may not need to attach them to external power (not just the arduino 5v). However, because you can not control how far they move, you will need buttons at the end of the race. I think you can get them from Adafruit.